# differentiate MDS and PCA in Julia

Tags: julia, pca, mds

I'm using both MDS and PCA in the package MultivariateStats.jl. My code is

```
 M = fit(PCA, matrix; maxoutdim=2)
Yte = predict(M, matrix)
M1 = fit(MDS, matrix; maxoutdim=2, distances=false)
Yte1 = predict(M1)
```

Soon I found that Yte and Yte1 are always the same since MDS uses Euclidean norm, so MDS is always equivalent to PCA in this case. Then I tried another method.

```
mds = fit(MDS, matrix; distances=true, metric=isotonic)
```

But I got the error that

> MethodError: no method matching fit(::Type{MDS}, ::Adjoint{Float64, Matrix{Float64}}; distances=true, metric=MultivariateStats.isotonic)
> Closest candidates are:
> fit(::Type{MDS}, ::AbstractMatrix{T}; maxoutdim, distances) where T<:Real at ~/.julia/packages/MultivariateStats/cFZlL/src/cmds.jl:232 got unsupported keyword argument "metric"

I found the example code above in https://juliastats.org/MultivariateStats.jl/dev/mds/#MultivariateStats.MetricMDS

Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Please [report it here](https://github.com/JuliaStats/MultivariateStats.jl/issues/new/choose). Open an issue with a title like `MethodError: no method matching fit(::Type{MDS}, ::Adjoint{Float64, Matrix{Float64}}` and paste your entire post there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation is wrong, try `MetricMDS` instead of `MDS`.

Comment: UndefVarError: MetricMDS not defined

Comment: Are you using v0.10.0 ?

Comment: I'm using v"1.8.1"

Comment: I mean version of MultivariateStats. Try updating: `] update MultivariateStats`

Comment: The same error after the update.